# how to protect registration form from spam

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-2

ASP.NET/Mono  MVC2 E-shop contains registration form which ask for mandatory customer name, address, phone password two times and some optional fields.

Should spam protection added to form ?
Form verifies that password and "repeat password" fields are the same.
Is this sufficient to prevent spam ?

If not which is the most reasonable way to add such protection ? Something like

- Antiforgery token
- Add some more validation to existing data (how)
- Add extra input (captcha)

jquery and jquery ui are used in client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antiforgery tokens are a good first step. There's really no reason not to use them on every form, so just make it a habit. The way they work is that when the user lands on your GET action, a token is created and set as either a hidden field in the form or a cookie or both. When the form is posted, the POST action checks that it's equal to the token that got set on the GET action. If the posted value and the original value match, the request is processed as normal. This means that some third-party cannot simply post data directly to your POST action. They must first load the GET action, get the antiforgery token and then POST using that. It's just one extra step, but in games like spamming and phishing, where it's more about volume than effectiveness, it at least slows them down. Instead of a script that might work for a range of URLs and sites, they must now custom write something just for your site. If you're Facebook, they'll do that. If it's your personal blog, they probably won't waste their time. It all depends on their motivations and how valuable they perceive your site to be.

Another relatively effective technique is called a honeypot. Basically, you add some field to your form that is usually something important, but which doesn't matter for the sake of the form in question - fields like "email", "name", etc. Pick one that your current form doesn't use, include it anyway, and then hide it with CSS or JS. (Keep in mind though that you need to *visibly* hide it, *not* set it to `display:none`. Fields with `display:none` are not posted, so it defeats the purpose -- you want it to be posted. Just set something like:

```
position:absolute;
width:0; height:0;
overflow:hidden;
```

Anyways, if the spammer is just randomly targeting sites, their script will go after your honeypot, and if they fill it in, you know it's a spammer, so you just throw away that post. Also, bear in mind that to make this technique effective, you have to *pretend* that it worked. So, even though you're actually throwing the post away behind the scenes, you still act like it was a successful request. If you return some error or fail completely with something like a 403 Forbidden, they'll get wise to what you're doing.

I would say that only if the first two suggestions above don't work to prevent spam, should you consider a CAPTCHA. They are extremely usability flawed and users hate them with a burning passion equal to the fires of the sun. Don't go overboard right from the start. Depending on the size of renown of your site, an antiforgery alone token might actually do the job. If not, a honeypot might, etc. To many people just go whole hog right off the bat and slap a CAPTCHA on everything, when more likely than not, spam will be minimal at best.

Comment: I've used the honeypot successfully several times in the past and am about to use it again.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that captcha is sufficient to prevent spam.

Comment: Captcha needs extra input. Form has many input fileds so I asked about preventing this. This is usual post action form. Is there something simpler, like Antiforgery token to prevent robots from posting or is it reasonable to add email activation

Comment: I don't really know much about antiforgery tokens so I can't comment on that, however I have found that email activation does little to prevent spam. Captcha is extra input but if the user is already filling out the registration form it shouldn't be a problem to fill out the captcha as well.